# SA Account has not been disabled

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security

There has been a security audit for many of our sql servers and per script there are many findings.

One of them says "SA Account has not been disabled"

I know it can be disabled, but can it be renamed.

Please confirm what should i go with "Remove, rename or disable the SA account" and whats he best practise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `sa` can be renamed *and* disabled since SQL Server 2005. It can't be removed

You can then if you wish, create a dummy `sa` account with, say, a GUID as password and then disable that or for any software that needs it.

Note that this will let you see the new name of the original `sa` account

SELECT SUSER_NAME(0x01)

Comment: Thanks , but would renaming in the very first place would make any impact on the application, in case it is using sa somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it will break an application that uses it: if an app does, I'd suggest it's a badly writtn app. It **won't** break SQL Server the application though

Comment: Thanks , you're answers explained what i was looking for, but i would like to know on elast about its password expiration policy, report says, passwd expiration check not applied. any idea on this ?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx for CHECK_POLICY etc